# Can you add a caption for a photo Using Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

So I am able to upload a photo to Facebook using the code below.

```
  FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(activity, image).build();
  uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

but I would now like to have a caption along with it. Is that possible?

Comment: Can't the user input one in the share dialog?

Comment: They can but I would like to have one in there already

Comment: I assume you haven't read https://developers.facebook.com/policy and specifically 2.3: "Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions."

Comment: It is really nice. Much less spam

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because of Facebook's developer policies ->

https://developers.facebook.com/policy